# What known bugs still exist in SQL Server 2005 after SP4 CU4?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm assuming CU4 will be the last update for SQL 2005.  We intend to stay on 2005 for awhile.  Does anyone know (or perhaps a list is maintained) which bugs STILL exist on 2005?  I assume these would mainly be bugs that have been fixed in 2008 and 2012, but still exist in 2005, even after applying SP4 CU4.

Seems like we should track this if we are staying on 2005...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't really keep a public list of open bugs. The ones that are the most important (e.g. anything involving security) are kept private for obvious reasons - they actually aren't published until they are fixed (and even then they often remain private). Not that there have been many security issues with SQL Server in the past 12 years, but by necessity, we don't know what we don't know.

And to be honest keeping such a list out in the open would be like BMW keeping a bulletin board with all the problems that still exist on their 2006 M3. It's kind of like a dirty laundry list, and other than satisfying customers who refuse to upgrade to more modern (and arguably "more fixed") versions, what would it do for them? :-)

Now, you could go out to http://connect.microsoft.com/sql/ and peruse the list of bugs opened against SQL Server 2005 that are still open. But that wouldn't be the whole story, since many bugs were opened against 2005, then closed as fixed when the fix was actually implemented in a more modern version. Never mind the large number that were closed as by design or not reproducible but that still affect you to this day.

You could also go to the knowledge base http://support.microsoft.com/kb and try to find all of the issues listed there that haven't been updated to include the text "this issue has been fixed in [such and such update]." This would also be a Herculean task that I would not wish against my worst enemies.

In the end, if you are not affected by bugs you do not know about, they may as well not exist, right? And if you are continuing active development against SQL Server 2005 and you come across an issue, it is highly, highly unlikely that you will be the first person to come across it. So if you come here for assistance you will stand a very good chance at getting the guidance you need - either a workaround to get around the bug by coding the query a different way, or a trace flag, query hint, or a completely different approach.

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I'm quite afraid you're not going to get the answer you're looking for. This answer (and this site, to be honest) is quite possibly the next best thing. When you have a *specific* issue, bring it here, and we will help.

Comment: +1, but I am not with you on the following: "if you are not affected by bugs you do not know about, they may as well not exist, right? " The reason: some problems do not show up right away. They are in fact time bombs, causing trouble later. An example: Columnstore Index Returns Incorrect Data - it only makes itself visible when several stars are aligned, right?

Comment: @Alex That depends on how far you are pushing SQL Server 2005 today and how likely you are to come across some new bug that nobody has ever discovered before. That is far more likely to occur in a new feature in a new version than the most popularly deployed version on the planet, where all known "incorrect results" bugs have been fixed. Do you know of any incorrect results bugs that have not been fixed? Do you know if there are any bugs that haven't been fixed but haven't been disclosed?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the detailed and very well thought out comment.  I think you are correct that the likelihood of an "incorrect result" bug still existing on 2005 is very small (which is one reason I like being a version or two back).  It also makes perfect sense that Microsoft would not be vested in trying to maintain such a list.  I was actually hoping a third party might be.  My guess is that alot of people are still on 2005, and will be for several years (in developing countries, perhaps even longer).  Anyway, thanks for the great reply (and to Alex and Shawn as well).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Actually, your suggestion to use the Connect site might give me what i want - even if the bugs were fixed in a later version, I don't care (I just want to see any that remain in 2005).  But, does that site contain all known bugs, or just those opened by the community (i.e. what about bugs discovered internally at Microsoft and release in a KB or something?).  (and, yes, I *am* back looking at this 4 years later ... still a frustrating issue)

Comment: @Scott No, Microsoft doesn't use Connect to document internally found bugs, or even externally found bugs raised by customers but not through Connect.

Comment: OK thanks @AaronBertrand , I give up, then. :-)  We have upgraded to 2012 but I would still like a list of outstanding bugs - crazy this doesn't exist.  Even though I'm doing the standard two versions back thing, I still have to worry about what I don't know hurting me.

Comment: For Microsoft's SQL Server engineers to build and maintain a list of fixed/unresolved bugs for SQL Server 2005 would take a lot of work. For all that would gain and for all we would lose in opportunity cost, sorry, I'm not going to be able to agree with you. Worry about bugs when they actually hurt you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry maybe wasn't clear - we are on 2012 now.  I would like it for versions still under support.  I mean, the advice is to be on a version or two back, but if I follow that advice, shouldn't i be able to see a list of known bugs (which I assume they are working on since 2012 is still under support).  I agree 2005 is a bit crazy.

Comment: @ScottEdwards2000 I still think that even for supported versions what you're asking for is unreasonable and I still argue that I'd rather have the engineers spend time on fixing bugs and improving features rather than maintain some master list. Microsoft does document *most* bugs in the knowledge base (except ones that would reveal vulnerabilities), fixed or not, and shows which versions or affected and where the fix exists, if it exists. Those documents (along with the fix list for an SP or CU) are a nightmare to maintain on their own, never mind some master list.

Comment: @ScottEdwards2000 Remember, too, that not every "bug" that gets reported on Connect is actually a bug.

Answer (score 0):

100% agreement with @Aaron on this.

Athough your comment `Seems like we should track this if we are staying on 2005...` strikes a chord with most folks I am sure...

You should not be planning to stay on SQL Server 2005, that follows the normal lifecycle support Microsoft has for everyone of their products. This goes along with what Aaron spoke of regarding bugs that are marked fixed in the next release, be it SQL 2008, 2008 R2 or even 2012. The same fate is meet with the operating system as well. If you move your SQL 2005 instance to each new release of the OS you are going to hit a release that will not support SQL 2005 being run on it.

That is just the normal business planning that has to be considered when working in a Windows environment, and if you work in other environments as well I am sure.